# Why does this function produce an error in truffle but not not in remix?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I have a string handling library, consisting of several functions, but only one of them produces an error when I run it in truffle test.  (The other functions seems to work fine.). This function does not produce an error in the remix IDE.

The error is:
Error: `Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.`

The function is a substring function:

```
 /* Note startPos is 1-based */
 function getSlice(string memory source, uint startPos, uint numChars) public pure returns (string memory) {
   uint ustartPos = uint(startPos -1);
   uint _numChars = uint(numChars);

    bytes memory sourcebytes = bytes(source);
   if (_numChars==0) {
       _numChars = ((sourcebytes.length - ustartPos) + 1);
   }
  
  bytes memory result = new bytes(_numChars);     

  for (uint i = 0; i<_numChars; i++) {
      result[i] = sourcebytes[i + ustartPos];
  }
  return string(result);
}
```

Other functions in my library use `getSlice` (e.g. `replaceString`) but tests of those functions pass.  I suspect then, something wrong with the truffle test case for `getSlice`, not the function itself, but I'm not seeing it.  Here is the test case.

```
  it('can get a slice from a string', async () => {
    let lib = await BKopyStrings.deployed();
    let string = "Now is the time";
    let result = await lib.getSlice(string, 5, 2);
    assert.equal(result,"is", "result should be 'is'");
  })
```

Comment: What is the default gas in your truffle config ?

Comment: 6721975 set in truffle-config.js config which I think is some kind of limit